# Connect to MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Desktop CrmConnection

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

My client is using the hosted edition, and not the online version, of Dynamics CRM 2011. Using my C# code, how would I obtain the user name, password, URL and device ID to authenticate? Using the CRM 2011 online, I can connect using this code. I believe device ID is hard coded.

```
CrmConnection crmConnection = CrmConnection.Parse(String.Format("Url={0}; Username={1}; Password=   
{2};DeviceID=enterprise-ba9f6b7b2e6d; DevicePassword=passcode;", url, username, password));

OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(crmConnection);
var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(service);
return xrm;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hosted version (OnPremise) relies on Active Directory authentication (`DOMAIN\USERNAME`), so you need to add `Domain` to your connection string and remove `DeviceID` and `DevicePassword` (they are necessary only for CRM Online using LiveId authentication)

The code will be:

```cs
CrmConnection crmConnection =
CrmConnection.Parse(String.Format("Url={0}; Username={1}; Password={2}; Domain={3}", url, username, password, domain));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just delete deviceid and devicepassword. Also check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx) that describes how to use CrmConnection class.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientCredentials Credentials = new ClientCredentials();
Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

/This URL needs to match the servername and Organization for the environment.

```
Uri OrganizationUri = new Uri("http://crm/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
Uri HomeRealmUri = null;

using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null))
{

    IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService)serviceProxy;
    if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
       {
         string EUserName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
          string WinUserName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
          UserName.InnerText = EUserName;
       }
}


Also add references
**microsoft.crm.sdk.proxy**
**microsoft.xrm.sdk**
```